# analytical proof for Jacobi identity

Tags: geometry

I need proof 
I am in need of major assistance with a homework problem I have been working on
$$\vec a(\vec b\times \vec c)+
\vec b(\vec c\times \vec a)+
\vec c(\vec a\times \vec b)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that:
$$ f(a,b,c)\triangleq a\times(b\times c)+b\times(c\times a)+c\times(a\times b) $$
is zero for every choice of $a,b,c$ among the elements of the canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Obviously $f(e_i,e_i,e_i)=0$, while:
$$ f(e_i,e_i,e_j) = e_i\times e_k + e_i\times(-e_k) + e_j\times 0 = 0, $$
$$ f(e_i,e_j,e_k) = e_i\times e_i + e_j\times e_j + e_k\times e_k = 0,$$
so, by linearity, $f(a,b,c)=0$ for every choice of $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\vec{a}\times\pars{\vec{b}\times\vec{c}}&=\pars{\vec{c}\cdot\vec{a}}\vec{b}
-\pars{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{a}}\vec{c}
\\
\vec{b}\times\pars{\vec{c}\times\vec{a}}&=\pars{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}\vec{c}
-\pars{\vec{c}\cdot\vec{b}}\vec{a}
\\
\vec{c}\times\pars{\vec{a}\times\vec{b}}&=\pars{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}}\vec{a}
-\pars{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}}\vec{b}
\end{align}

> Add both members and you get the expected result.